# Need to improve performance in Active Directory (adlds) inatance

Tags: active-directory

We have a (client [Android]-server[C#]) application which can handle 200000 users. MSSQL server is used to store users and groups.

But, recently we had to switch to Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (Windows) instance to store uses and groups. After the change we noticed that our application is slow when comparing to the earlier.

After the change our solution cannot handle flowing Load Test scenario which worked fine previously.

Load Test scenario--

100000 clients connect to server within one hour. Each client request users and groups according to there category. Each client send positions, memos, scanning data to the server and server store them in the database.

Result--

Around 32000 clients get connected within one hour.

We did some change to the code to improve the performance, but didn't help much. Now around 60000 clients get connected within one hour.

Are there any other improvements that we can do? Like indexing, load balancing?

Please help us...

Comment: Have you profiled the code and seen where your slow spots are? Are they specifically around your interactions with AD LDS? If so, can you post the code snippets and what performance metrics you're seeing for them?

Comment: How are you retrieving data from ADLDS? Are you using `AccountManagement` class or the old `Directory Entry`? It be helpful if you provide some code...